# Java <key, value> collection to retrieve minimum element in O(1) or O(log(n)) at worst

Tags: java, collections, minimum

I'm iterating through a huge file reading key and value from every line. I need to obtain specific number (say 100k) of elements with highest values. To store them I figured that I need a collection that allows me to check a minimum value in O(1) or O(log(n)) and if currently read value is higher then remove element with minimum value and put new one. What collection enables me to do that? Values are not unique so BiMap is probably not adequate here.

EDIT:
Ultimate goal is to obtain best [key, value] that will be used later. Say my file looks like below (first column - key, second value):
3 6
5 9
2 7
1 6
4 5
Let's assume I'm looking for best two elements and algorithm to achieve that. I figured that I'll use a key-based collection to store best elements. First two elements (<3, 6>, <5, 9>) will be obviously added to the collection as its capacity is 2. But when I get to the third line I need to check if <2, 7> is eligible to be added to the collection (so I need to be able to check if 7 is higher than minimum value in collection (6)

Comment: This isn't entirely clear - how does the minimum-value stuff interact with the fact you have key-based lookup?  A concrete example would be helpful :)

Comment: With your edit clarifying that you really did mean "index by key but order by value," it really is not clear what you're trying to do. Do you even need to preserve the first column at all? In what way will the numbers of the first column be used? It sounds like the second column should actually be the key and the first column should be the mapped value.

Comment: @Aaron, definitely I need both :) First column (keys) are coded chess positions (their fragments) and second (values) are their evaluation.

Comment: So the top two are `5 9` and `2 7`, right? What if you wanted top 3? Does that include `3 6` or `1 6`, given that they have the same rank (`6`)?

Comment: Yep, the top two are 5 9 and 2 7. In case of the same rank it doesn't matter which is chosen.

Comment: @stanwar Do you really need to index by location, or do you just need to keep track of what the locations are that have good ratings? That is, will you ever be doing a lookup by location, or will you just be grabbing the best value (or best `n` values) and then using their associated locations? If you do not need to index by location, that makes the problem easier.

Comment: @Aaron, I don't need to index by location. It was only my first concept as I was circling around TreeMap or similar.

Comment: @stanwar I made a mistake in my previous answer edit. The mistake caused a problem with removing elements. I have fixed it. Take note of the caveat I edited in about some set functionality being lost. It should still do everything you need though. With the problem I had to work around, I think the set might be little more than a fancy sorted queue (or deque rather, since you can use both ends). At this point I'm not sure which is better, the `PriorityQueue` suggested elsewhere, or the `TreeSet`, so try them both.

Comment: If your goal is to find the best single item, why are you collecting the top 100K items?

Comment: My goal is to find 100K best items.

Comment: Anyone care to provide constructive feedback? I put a lot of effort into helping OP provide needed data, and I have maintained a good answer all the while. After the most recent updates, my answer covers nearly every angle, contains relevant quotes and links and provides examples. Still, oddly, question has +3 (got +1 even when it was still confusing), but most of the answers are sitting at -1 or 0, including mine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't actually need a  structure because you are simply looking for the largest N values with their corresponding keys, and the keys are not actually used for sorting or retrieval for the purpose of this problem.

I would use the [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), with the minimum value at the root. This allows you to retrieve the smallest element in constant time, and if your next value is larger, removal and insertion in O(log N) time.

```
class V{
    int key;
    int value;
}

class ComparatorV implements Comparator<V>{
    int compare(V a, V b){
        return Integer.compare(a.value, b.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aaron There is nothing in the question that says result has to be ordered, just that result has to be top 100k values *("I need to obtain specific number (say 100k) of elements with highest values")*. That is to accumulate the top values from a huge file without running out of memory. If the result does need to be sorted, that can easily be done at the end. It seems unlikely that top values needs to be in order *while* reading the huge file, so there should be no need for multiple sorts.

Comment: @Aaron There is no "grab last n". The entire point is that it will never have more than `n` values, otherwise you'll run out of memory loading the entire "huge" file.

Comment: @Aaron Where does it say only the top two is needed? If you're referring to the edit, that is a reduced *example*, to show how needing top 2 of 5 would work. Real code needs top 100k of "huge" file.

Comment: @Andreas line of thought is what I meant.

Comment: `a.value - b.value` can overflow. Better to use `Integer.compare(a.value, b.value)`

Answer (score 0):

For your specific situation, you can use a `TreeSet`, and to get around the uniqueness of elements in a set you can store pairs which are comparable but which never appear equal when compared. This will allow you to violate the contract with `Set` which specifies that the `Set` not contain equal values.

The documentation for `TreeSet` contains:

> The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract
>   of the Set interface

So using the `TreeSet` with the `Comparable` inconsistent with `equals` should be fine in this situation. If you ever need to compare your chess pairs for a different reason (perhaps some other algorithm you are also running in this app) where the comparison should be consistent with equals, then provide a `Comparator` for the other use. Notice that `TreeSet` has a constructor which takes a `Comparator`, so you can use that instead of having `ChessPair` implement `Comparable`.

Notice: A `TreeSet` provides more flexibility than a `PriorityQueue` in general because of all of its utility methods, but by violating the "comparable consistent with equals" contract of `Set` some of the functionality of the `TreeSet` is lost. For example, you can still remove the first element of the set using `Set.pollFirst`, but you cannot remove an arbitrary element using `remove` since that will rely on the elements being equivalent.

Per your "`n` or at worst `log(n)`" requirement, the documentation also states:

> This implementation provides guaranteed **log(n)** time cost for the basic
>   operations (add, remove and contains).

Also, I provide an optimization below which reduces the minimum-value query to **O(1)**.

### Example

```
Set s = new TreeSet<ChessPair>();
```

and

```
public class ChessPair implements Comparable<ChessPair>
{
    final int location;
    final int value;

    public ChessPair(final int location, final int value)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ChessPair o)
    {
        if(value < o.value) return -1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now you have an ordered set containing your pairs of numbers, they are ordered by your value, you can have duplicate values, and you can get the associated locations. You can also easily grab the first element (`set.first`), last (`set.last`), or get a sub-set (`set.subSet(a,b)`), or iterate over the first (or last, by using `descendingSet`) `n` elements. This provides everything you asked for.

### Example Use

You specified wanting to keep the 100 000 best elements. So I would use one algorithm for the first 100 000 possibilities which simply adds every time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000 && dataSource.hasNext(); i += 1)
{
    ChessPair p = dataSource.next(); // or whatever you do to get the next line
    set.add(p);
}
```

and then a different one after that

```
while(dataSource.hasNext())
{
    ChessPair p = dataSource.next();
    if(p.value > set.first().value)
    {
        set.remove(set.pollFirst());
        set.add(p);
    }
}
```

### Optimization

In your case, you can insert an optimization into the algorithm where you compare against the lowest value. The above, simple version performs an O(log(n)) operation every time it compares against minimum-value since `set.first()` is O(log(n)). Instead, you can store the minimum value in a local variable.

This optimization works well for scaling this algorithm because the impact is negligible - no gain, no loss - when `n` is close to the total data set size (ie: you want best 100 values out of 110), but when the total data set is vastly larger than `n` (ie: best 100 000 out of 100 000 000 000) the query for the minimum value is going to be your most common operation and will now be constant.

So now we have (after loading the initial `n` values)...

```
int minimum = set.first().value;
while(dataSource.hasNext())
{
    ChessPair p = dataSource.next();
    if(p.value > minimum)
    {
        set.remove(set.pollFirst());
        set.add(p);
        minimum = set.first().value;
    }
}
```

Now your most common operation - query minimum value - is constant time (O(1)), your second most common operation - add - is worst case log(n) time, and your least most common operation - remove - is worst case log(n) time.

For arbitrarily large data sets, each input is now processed in constant O(1) time.

See [java.util.TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

---

**Previous answer (now obsolete)**

Based on question edits and discussion in the question's comments, I no longer believe my original answer to be correct. I am leaving it below for reference.

If you want a `Map` collection which allows fast access to elements based on order, then you want an ordered `Map`, for which there is a sub-interface `SortedMap`. Fortunately for you, Java has a great implementation of `SortedMap`: it's `TreeMap`, a `Map` which is backed by a "red-black" tree structure which is an ordered tree.

Red-black-trees are nice since they rotate branches in order to keep the tree balanced. That is, you will not end up with a tree that branches `n` times in one direction, yielding `n` layers, just because your data may already have been sorted. You are guaranteed to have approximately `log(n)` layers in the tree, so it is always fast and guarantees `log(n)` query even for worst-case.

For your situation, try out the [java.util.TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). On the page linked in the previous sentence, there are links also to `Map` and `SortedMap`. You should check out the one for `SortedMap` too, so you can see where `TreeMap` gets some of the specific functionality that you are looking for. It allows you to get the first key, the last key, and a sub-map that fetches a range from within this map.

For your situation though, it is probably sufficient to just grab an iterator from the `TreeMap` and iterate over the first `n` pairs, where `n` is the number of lowest (or highest) values that you want.

Comment: TreeMap doesn't allow to get element with lowest/highest value.

Comment: firstEntry and lastEntry return elements with lowest/highest key, not value.

Comment: Ahh, OP's edit clarifies that OP actually did mean value where it said value. That does complicate this a bit.

Comment: @stanwar Sounds like you're thinking about this backwards. For this particular data structure, use a TreeMap. The "values" from your source will be the keys for your TreeMap, and the "keys" from your source will be the values for your TreeMap. Since you mentioned multiple keys can have the same value, you can use an ArrayList, or a TreeSet for extra sorting. **TL;DR: use a `java.util.TreeMap<Value, ArrayList<Key>>`**

Comment: @8bittree Thank you for reminding us that OP says values are not unique. I would agree that, depending on the situation, mapping to a `List` of values can remedy this, but I would suggest that it is not clear what OP's aim is and we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TreeSet`, which offers O(log n) insertion and O(1) retrieval of either the highest or lowest scored item.

Your item class must:

- Implement `Comparable`
- Not implement `equals()`

To keep the top 100K items only, use this code:

```
Item item; // to add
if (treeSet.size() == 100_000) {
    if (treeSet.first().compareTo(item) < 0) {
        treeSet.remove(treeSet.first());
        treeSet.add(item);
    }
} else {
    treeSet.add(item);
}
```

Comment: `TreeSet` is backed by `TreeMap`, and if I recall, retrieving the highest or lowest value is O(log(n)). Last I looked at its source code, I don't recall it making the optimization to keep track of the min/max values separately. I'll look into it to verify. Also, this answer duplicates a previous answer that went into more detail.

Comment: I just looked it up again. Although `TreeMap` (and by extension `TreeSet`) probably could optimize `first` and `last`, they do not. Calls to `first` and `last` traverse the tree from root to the appropriate min or max leaf.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a collection ordered by values, you can use a TreeSet which stores tuples of your keys and values. A TreeSet has O(log(n)) access times.

```
class KeyValuePair<Key, Value: Comparable<Value>> implements Comparable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> {
    Key key;
    Value value;

    KeyValuePair(Key key, Value value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compare(KeyValuePair<Key, Value> other) {
        return this.value.compare(other.value);
    }
}
```

or instead of implementing `Comparable`, you can pass a `Comparator` to the set at creation time.

You can then retrieve the first value using `treeSet.first().value`.

Comment: This does not allow multiple entries with the same value.

Comment: @Aaron OP mentioned he wanted a collection sorted by value (as mentioned in a comment to your answer).

Comment: @Palle Yes, that isn't what I meant, but what I meant doesn't matter anyway since OP has clarified more, rendering my comment moot. So never mind. (and by the way, I am not the source of your -1)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

entry for your data structure, that can be sorted based on the value

```
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
    public final String key;
    public final long value;
    public Entry(String key, long value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Entry other) {
        return this.value - other.value;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        //hashcode based on the same values on which equals works
    }
}
```

actual code that works with a `PriorityQueue`. The sorting is based on the value, not on the key as with a TreeMap. This is because of the compareMethod defined in `Entry`. If the sets grows above 100000, the lowest entry (with the lowest value) is removed.

```
public class ProcessData {
    private int maxSize;
    private PriorityQueue<Entry> largestEntries = new PriorityQueue<>(maxSize);

    public ProcessData(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public void addKeyValue(String key, long value) {
        largestEntries.add(new Entry(key, value));
        if (largestEntries.size() > maxSize) {
            largestEntries.poll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not allow multiple entries with the same value.

Comment: I would if the Entry.equals() method is dropped

Comment: Nope. `TreeSet` does not use `equals()`.

Comment: Updated answer, use PriorityQueue instead of TreeSet. A PriorityQueue allows multiple same values.